# Kth smallest element of an Array using Quick Sort algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

I am trying to solve this challenge:

> Return the K<sup>th</sup> smallest element of an array using the quick sort algorithm

I am not getting proper output for the following input:

```
int arr[] = {3, 2, 1};
int k = 2;
```

I don't see where is my mistake.

My c++ code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int partion(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    int x = arr[r];
    int i = l - 1;
    int j;
    for (j = l; j < r; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < x)
        {
            i++;
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(arr[r], arr[i + 1]);
    return i + 1;
}

int quick(int arr[], int l, int r, int k)
{
    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1)
    {
        int m = partion(arr, l, r);
        return m == k - 1 ? arr[m] : k - 1 < m ? quick(arr, l, m - 1, k)
                                               : quick(arr, m + 1, r, k - m + l - 1);
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}
```

So when I run this code:

```
int arr[] = {3, 2, 1};
int k = 2;
std::cout << quick(arr, 0, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int), k);
```

The output I get is INT_MAX, while 2 is expected.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Tried any debugging yet? What were your findings?

Comment: I tried debugging and I got some huge number instead of the correct output

Comment: i expected to get kth smallest element but i got some huge number as it returns INT_MAX in all cases

Answer (score 1):

Your `quick` function lacks the (positive) base case: when the range covers just one element (and `k` is 1), the function should return that element without further recursion.

So add that base case inside the `if` block:

```
    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1)
    {
        if (l == r) return arr[l];   // <--- base case
        // ...rest of your code
    }
```